# get modification time of included file

Tags: php, date, include

I try to get the modification dateof a included file. 
If I use this:

```
echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y.", getlastmod());
```

I get the date of the parent file, I want the date of the file i include.
Btw, this piece of code is in my included file and not in the parent file.

How can I get the date of the file I include?

Comment: Use the `stat()` function, it takes a filename argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function, for example:

```
date ("F d Y.", filemtime('path_to_your_file'))
```

Take a look at php's docs on [getlastmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getlastmod.php):

> Gets the time of the last modification of the current page.
>
> If you're interested in getting the last modification time of a
>   different file, consider using filemtime().

You're getting the last modification of the parent, because the parent is the file that you're executing and it doesn't matter which file you include or require. One PHP file is executed and that's the relevant one. That's why you should explicitly state which file you want to get the last mod date of.